# SQL group need related value instead of aggregate function

Tags: sql-server

Have a table like this

```
FileID  Value    Version
-------------------------
1       Welle       2
1       Achse       3
2       Box         5
2       Enclosure   7
```

I need to "sum" up the lines with same FileID -> take highest value from column VERSION and get back the related value.

Desired result would be:

```
FileID  Value    Version
-------------------------
1       Achse       3
2       Enclosure   7
```

However using GROUP By sums up, but brings wrong result for Value:

```
SELECT 
    [FileID],
    MAX([Value]),
    MAX([Version])
FROM [ValueMist]
GROUP BY FileID
```

This returns:

```
 FileID  Value   Version
 ------------------------
 1       Welle     3
 2       Enclosure 7
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is `WITH TIES` in concert with `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by FileId Order By version desc)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be pretty strong, heading to what I am looking for!

Comment: @Volker Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **ROW NUMBER**

```
     ;WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY 
      ID ORDER BY VERSION DESC) AS RW 
       FROM TABLE)

       SELECT * FROM CTE
        WHERE RW=1
```